# Creare a Copy of 2D Array in Angular 2 Class

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, angular

I'm trying to copy a 2D array in to another array in Angular 2 class. I tried a solution but not getting any output.

Here's the code (Not getting the output): http://plnkr.co/edit/s9vFKEw4y4aKtQRUGfev?p=preview

Html Code:

```
Testing Array a:
    <ul *ngFor="let arra of a">
            <li>{{arra[0]}}</li>
            <li>{{arra[1]}}</li>
        </ul>

   Testing Array b:
    <ul *ngFor="let arrb of b">
            <li>{{arrb[0]}}</li>
            <li>{{arrb[1]}}</li>
        </ul>
```

Class code:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]];
    clone() {
    var arr = this.slice(0);
    for( var i = 0; i < this.length; i++ ) {
        if( this[i].clone ) {
            //recursion
            arr[i] = this[i].clone();
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

var b = a.clone()
```

Is there any way i can copy the array in to another array in Angular2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work because you try to use method of Array class that does not exist (clone()). You just defined a function clone(), but it's not part of Array's prototype. 
Change `clone() {` to `Array.prototype.clone = function() {`

This should work, but for operations of this kind I'd suggest you to check out lodash. https://lodash.com/docs#clone

Comment: After i add the changes you told, it's still not working. Check:http://plnkr.co/edit/s9vFKEw4y4aKtQRUGfev?p=preview

Comment: I modified your component code a bit. Check it out: http://plnkr.co/edit/0n1qD8Xa5kJv9d3A4416?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the answer.